# oracle jdk17 in docker Failed to start thread "GC Thread#0"

Tags: java, docker

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM frolvlad/alpine-glibc
RUN echo http://mirrors.aliyun.com/alpine/v3.10/main/ > /etc/apk/repositories && echo http://mirrors.aliyun.com/alpine/v3.10/community/ >> /etc/apk/repositories && apk update
RUN apk add -U tzdata
RUN ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime && echo 'Asia/Shanghai' >/etc/timezone
ENV LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE=zh_CN.UTF-8

ADD jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz /usr/java

RUN ln -s /usr/java/jdk-17.0.6 /usr/java/default
ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

**docker version**

Docker version 17.04.0-ce, build 4845c56

**JDK version**

```
java version "17.0.6" 2023-01-17 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+9-LTS-190)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.6+9-LTS-190, mixed mode, sharing)
```

If I do not add `--security-opt seccomp=unconfined` in docker run command, it returns the error below

```
/ # java -version
[0.118s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread "GC Thread#0" - pthread_create failed (EPERM) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 4k, detached.
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Cannot create worker GC thread. Out of system resources.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# //hs_err_pid6.log
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead [edit] your question to include the output as properly formatted text.

Comment: Did you got the answer?